# How to stack points based on their latitude and longitude value on a raster image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, latitude-longitude

I have a Sentinel2 image. I have a CSV file that contains latitude, longitude and precipitation data over the location where the sentinel2 image was taken. Now I want to stack the precipitation data over the image. So that I will be able to find out the locations where precipitation data were not available. In fact, I will be able to visualize my data clearly. Will I able to apply this on QGIS?

Comment: Yes! What have you tried and why didnt it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can visualize your data in QGIS.

1. Open QGIS.
2. Load the image as a raster. See the QGIS manual for [instructions on loading data into QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#loading-a-layer-from-a-file).
3. Load the CSV as a vector.
4. In the Layer Panel, make sure the CSV layer is above the raster.

The CSV will appear as points displayed over the image. See the following style sections of the QGIS Manual for instructions on changing point color, transparency, etc:

- [Vector style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#the-style-manager)
- [Raster style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#symbology-properties)